# Large number error with the Python Turtle

Tags: python, typeerror, turtle-graphics

I am reading a set of coordinates from a file to produce a shape in the Python Turtle. After reading reading in the coordinates, I have written a for loop that goes through the list of coords and draws them. However, upon running with a correct file name, I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\06113\Desktop\My Stuff\Python Saves\Vec Draw\Vec Draw.py", line 55, in <module>
    t.goto(cs)
  File "C:\Users\06113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1774, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(*x))
  File "C:\Users\06113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 3195, in _goto
    self._update() #count=True)
  File "C:\Users\06113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\06113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2650, in _update_data
    self.screen._drawline(self.currentLineItem, self.currentLine,
  File "C:\Users\06113\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 543, in _drawline
    cl.append(x * self.xscale)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Is there any way at all that I could fix this in MY file? I would rather not go into the turtle module where I could easily mess something up.

The code for this section in my file is:

```
t = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
t.speed(0)

for i in range(0, len(coord_list), 2):
    if i == 0 and i+1 == 1:
        fcs = (coord_list[i], coord_list[i+1])
        t.pu()
        t.goto(fcs)
        t.pd()
        pass
    else:
        cs = (coord_list[i], coord_list[i+1])
        t.goto(cs)
        cs = None
        pass
    pass

t.goto(fcs)
print("Vector image drawn.")
```

Comment: Your coordinates are apparently strings.  Use `int()` to turn them into numbers that can actually be used as parameters to turtle methods.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to solve this problem for about a month.